# Redirect a page using handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I redirect a page when a session is not filled out in asp.net handler?

Comment: What do you mean by "not filled out"?

Comment: an iteration where there will be a validation if a user is currently logged. In every login, i'm creating a session and that will be checked in handler.

Comment: I do the same thing using cookies, less pressure on server.

Answer (score 0):

Add following class into app_code (root of site)

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class SecurityCrm
    Implements IHttpModule


Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Dispose

End Sub

Public Sub Init(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Init
    AddHandler context.BeginRequest, AddressOf FirstTest
End Sub

Private Sub FirstTest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim app As HttpApplication
    app = CType(sender, HttpApplication)


        Dim cookie As HttpCookie ' Replace with Session Object



        cookie = app.Request.Cookies("username") ' Replace with your Session

        If cookie Is Nothing Then
            app.Response.redirect("/Cms/LoginSystem/login.asp?u=" & app.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
            app.Response.end()
        Else
            'app.Response.write("Cookie: " & cookie.value)
        End If


End Sub
```

End Class

Then Register it in web.config.

```
  <httpModules>
    <add type="SecurityCrm" name="SecurityCrm.app_code" />
  </httpModules>
```